# How can i separate or print 2 selectors on different page using printThis?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf-generation, printthis

I just want to print 2 elements but when I do it does not look well. My alternative solution was two buttons per element but it is not good.

I used this library https://github.com/jasonday

Here is the preview

[image]

When im going to print/download here is the preview
[image]

Are there any ways to separate them?

Here is my print code. I got 2 elements.
`$("#pdf, #pdf2").printThis();`

Comment: Just identify the pages you want to print and separate the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add css style "break-after: page;" between the two section/table

```
<div> Section </div>

<div style="break-after:page;" ></div>

<div> Section </div>
```